# Get Jar to run from web page click

Tags: java, tomcat

This seems like a duplicate, but I haven't been able to get anything to work. I'm trying to get a test server running in Vista, and am using Tomcat. I have a Jar file that runs the test (basically a bunch of api calls), and emails the user at the end with results. The complete jsp (linked from another page):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar c:\\Project.jar");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  %>
  Tests are running
  </body>
</html>
```

However, nothing happens. I can see in the task manager that a new java instance kicks off, but it never does anything. I ran the command `java -jar Project.jar` (in the c:\ drive) in the command prompt and it works. The only output I get is the "Tests are running" from the html, no error or anything. Any assistance on debugging or how to get the jar to run would be helpful. One note, I know a lot of questions deal with running the Jar on the client machine, here, I don't want that, I just want the server to run the Jar. This is a convenient way to deploy the file internally without anyone having to install anything. It's basically a button that gets the jar file running. Thanks!

Comment: Is client and server same in your case ?

Comment: No, for testing it might be, but I want others in the department to be able to click run in the webpage and kick off the Jar.

Comment: Well this might happen for several reasons then. Live debug can help for sure.

Comment: By putting break points, divide and conquer technique etc.

Comment: The only line I have is Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar c:\\Project.jar"); . I don't know how to output debugging info with this. The Jar file runs to the end when I run it on its own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91643/discussion-between-ss--and-user3476534).

Comment: In fact, when I put this same script into eclipse, it runs without a problem.

Comment: try to give the full path to java.exe

Comment: Changed the path, but same behavior. It creates a java.exe process, but it never performs any action. Used Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java -jar c:\\Project.jar");

Comment: I verified my firewall wasn't blocking apache or any java programs. In fact, it had no log for when the java process was running.